# Why str replace worked in first matched only?

Tags: php, css, preg-replace, preg-match, str-replace

My code:

```
$css=".class1{
    padding:1330px 2220px 0 auto;
    padding:10px auto 0 20px;
    padding:101px auto 0 200px;
}";

$search=self::extract_unit($css,"padding:",";");
```

extract_unit: this function extracts content between [padding:] and [;]

will return 1330px auto 0 2220px

```
$replace=self::resort_padding_margin($search);
```

resort_padding_margin: this function resorts the content

will return 1330px 2220px 0 auto

```
$css = str_replace($search, $replace, $css);
echo $css;
```

when i apply this code the result will show like this :

```
.class1{
    padding:1330px auto 0 2220px;
    padding:10px auto 0 20px;
    padding:101px auto 0 200px;
}
```

So how can i use this method to apply all padding to be show like this

```
.class1{
    padding:1330px auto 0 2220px;
    padding:10px 20px 0 auto;
    padding:101px 200px 0 auto;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this to work, your `self::extract_unit` method has to return an array, one item per occurrence of `padding`.

Then your `self::resort_padding_margin` should accept the search array and return another array with the modifications. Alternatively, write a loop in your main code and store the results of each call to this method inside an array.

When done, you can pass both arrays to `str_replace`.

Btw, a CSS should only have one `padding` definition. You have three, which is a bit strange :)